# Stop a python script without losing data

Tags: python

We have been running a script on partner's computer for 18 hours.  We underestimated how long it would take, and now need to turn in the results.  Is it possible to stop the script from running, but still have access to all the lists we are building?

We need to add additional code to the one we are currently running that will use the lists being populated right now.  Is there a way to stop the process, but still use (what has been generated of) the lists in the next portion of code?

My partner was using python interactively.

---

**update**

We were able to successfully print the results and copy and paste after interrupting the program with control-C.

Comment: *many years from now* "And that, kids, is why we started logging to disk."

Comment: Not unless your code is already equipped to do so. But hey, you can bill your manager for those 18 hours and call it overtime. ;)

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/google/pyringe can help you. Doesn't work for python3, though. Maybe you find another debugger that can attach itself to a running script.

Comment: If you stop the process, all the memory is freed. Plain simple.

Comment: Googling around, I found [Pyrasite](http://pyrasite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which is supposed to let you inject code in a running process, or let you [drop into a shell](https://pyrasite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Shell.html) and execute commands in a running process. Seems to be working on Python 2 and 3, on Widows and Linux. I have never used it, so I don't know what it's worth...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Well, OP doesn't seem to need an answer anymore. But I'll answer anyway for anyone else coming accross this.
While it is true that stopping the program will delete all data from memory you can still save it. You can inject a debug session and save whatever you need before you kill the process.

Both PyCharm and PyDev support attaching their debugger to a running python application.
See [here](https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2015/02/feature-spotlight-python-debugger-and-attach-to-process/) for an explanation how it works in PyCharm.
Once you've attached the debugger, you can set a breakpoint in your code and the program will stop when it hits that line the next time. Then you can inspect all variables and run some code via the 'Evaluate' feature. This code may save whatever variable you need.

I've tested this with PyCharm 2018.1.1 Community Edition and Python 3.6.4.

In order to do so I ran this code which I saved as *test.py*

```
import collections
import time

data = collections.deque(maxlen=100)
i = 0
while True:
    data.append(i % 1000)
    i += 1
    time.sleep(0.001)
```

via the command `python3 test.py` from an external Windows PowerShell instance.
Then I've opened that file in PyCharm and attached the debugger. I set a Breakpoint at the line `i += 1` and it halted right there. Then I evaluated the following code fragment:

```
import json
with open('data.json', 'w') as ofile:
    json.dump(list(data), ofile)
```

And found all entries from `data` in the json file *data.json*.

---

Follow-up:
This even works in an interactive session! I ran the very same code in a jupyter notebook cell and then attached the debugger to the kernel. Still having *test.py* open, I set the breakpoint again on the same line as before and the kernel halted. Then I could see all variables from the interactive notebook session.

Comment: This saved me 3 days of work that would have been lost. ups :)

Comment: [This article from JetBrains blog](https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2015/02/feature-spotlight-python-debugger-and-attach-to-process/) explains this feature quite well

Comment: That's the one I also linked in my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. Stopping the program should also release all of the memory it was using.

edit: See Swenzel's comment for one way of doing it.