# How to stop a Jupyter Notebook loop without losing the data obtained so far

Tags: python, loops, jupyter-notebook

I'm in a similar situation to [Stop a python script without losing data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49904516/stop-a-python-script-without-losing-data/49905688#49905688).

I am currently using Jupyter Notebook, the notebook is open and running.

I was wondering exactly how to make the answer work for my case. I am not a programmer, so I would need a step by step if at all possible.

The loop that has been running for 2 days is the following:

```
data = []
for file_origin in onlyfiles:
    path_to_text = mypath + '/' + file_origin
    data.append(tratamiento_datos(path_to_text))
```

I would like to retrieve data, saving whatever I can from the loop.

Answer (score 1):

### Step 1:

Stop the jupyter notebook.
Go to `kernel` --> `Interrupt`

### Step 2:

Save the data to disk.

```py
import json
import time


# run this after stopping   
with open(f'data_1_{int(time.time())}.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(data))
```

NOTE: make sure the data in `data` list is json serializable. Or you can `pickle` it, whatever you like.

### Step 3:

Start it again.

```py
data = []

# start from where you left
index = onlyfiles.index(file_origin)

for file_origin in onlyfiles[index:]:
    path_to_text = mypath + '/' + file_origin
    data.append(tratamiento_datos(path_to_text))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just stop the runnig cell, everything appended to `data` will remain there. After that you can save `data` content to disk with `json` or whatever way compatible with your data.